# Not able to pull any docker image in windows 2019 server hangs at extracting

Tags: windows, docker, docker-build, windows-server-2019, nano-server

[image]
The docker pull commands hangs at extracting not able to pull any image.

Comment: With so many Docker Pulls happening during the day all over the world by thousands of developers, I cannot imagine that this is a problem with Docker. My strong guess is that this problem is on your end, like Internet or PC-capacity.